# Leaflet map and event with multiples geojson attached to the map

Tags: jquery, leaflet

On a leaflet map, i load and attach two differents geojson but the mouse click doesn't work with both attached. On one geojson, i want that can be clicked and the other not. Is-there a way to do that ?

This is my piece of code, i load multiples maps on the same page with two geojson for each map :

```
(function($){ 
  var map = L.map('mapcontainer').setView([45.760612, 6.333560], 16);
  L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.esri.com/">Esri</a>, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community',
      maxZoom: 18,
      id: 'map'
  }).addTo(map);

  $.getJSON( "/media/kml/building.geojson").done(function( databuilding ) {
      function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {      
      var popupContent = "<p>Building " +
                feature.properties.Name;

        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
            popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
        }

        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }

    L.geoJSON(databuilding, {

        style: function (feature) {
            return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
        },

        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
      }).addTo(map);    
  });

  $.getJSON( "/media/kml/zone.geojson").done(function( datazone ) {    
    L.geoJSON(datazone
      ).addTo(map);      
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks by advance

Comment: It looks like you've done what you're asking for already - you're adding a popup via the `onEachFeature` function on one file, and not on the other. Is it not working?

Comment: Nope it's not working, when i click with mouse it doesn't open the infobubble

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Comment: It shows in the console, in each geojson at line 1, column 1 but the file is right loaded

Answer (score 0):

I had reversed the loading of layers because it's only the last where the events are take in consideration